# Django: Send emails from a user's email_host

Tags: python, django, email

I'm looking to allow users to send emails from their own email adresses
how can I change the email_host setting from instance to instance?

```
email_host = user.profile.email_host
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

That can't work. Most email providers require some sort of authentication, to prevent being used as spam gateways. Instead provide a mailto: link which opens up the user's own email client.

Comment: I once reviewed a web based contact management system that ran only on IE 6 & 7 (in 2007) and installed an ActiveX component to make a "send list of emails from the client's copy of outlook" work.  It was a horrible horrible thing.

Comment: What if they provide the email and password?